# Android: retrofit Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

tengo el siguiente codigo para consumir datos desde la api de edamam pero me al correra la app me lanza el error de Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
alguien me dice que puedo hacer para solucionarlo por favor

```
           val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        val service:ApiService = retrofit.create<ApiService>(ApiService::class.java)
        service.getAllRecipe("bread",app_id,app_key).enqueue(object : Callback<List<Recipe>>{
            override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<Recipe>>, response: Response<List<Recipe>>?) {
                    val recetas = response!!.body()
                    Log.i(TAG, Gson().toJson(recetas))
            }



     class Recipe {
    private var uri:String? = null
    private var label:String? = null
    private var image:String? = null
    private var source:String? = null
    private var url:String? = null
    private var yield:Int = 0
    private var calories:Float = 0f
    private var totalNutrients:String? = null
    private var totalDaily:String? = null

}
```

Comment: Agrega tu objeto Recipe

Answer (score 0):

Es difícil decir sin ver el json.
Pero el mensaje de error dice que al intentar convertir el json en un objeto java, esperaba un array, pero obtuvo un objeto en su lugar.

Probablemente lo soluciones creando una clase que contenga la lista.

```
public class RecipeList {
  private List<Recipe> recipes;
  // ...
}
```

y cambiando el servicio para que ***getAllRecipe*** devuelva ***RecipeList***